# How do I stop my screensaver from darkening and pausing? It happens frequently and I need to stop this

Tags: screen, screensaver

My screen keeps dimming and while it is dimmed, it pauses for a few minutes and this happens very frequently. I have gone into settings in the desktop and screensaver, but this does no good. I have tried everything, but to no avail. How can I stop my screen from dimming and pausing? This is so very annoying! I have Linux ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Can you please help me? (I will need very specific instructions as I am not real familiar with ubuntu computer language. Please help me asap. Thank you! Dianne

Comment: "It pauses": you mean it hibernates ? sleeps (suspend to RAM) ? or it's only the screen ?

Comment: Well I thought it was only the screen, but it sometimes pauses like it is sleeping for about 4 min.  It dims and goes dark and I can't do anything at all.  I have to wait for those 4 min. Maybe it hibernates, but I have "never" checked in the system settings and have done everything, but to no avail. I thought maybe I could install caffeine in the terminal, but I don't know where the terminal is in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Can you help me find the terminal? I have the code to type in-or is there something else you know of as to how to stop this annoying dimming and pausing? Thank you, Dianne

Comment: Either open the dash with the "Windows" key and type terminal or type Ctrl-Alt-T. You will have a terminal running